# Stuck joining Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 to Active Directory

Tags: ubuntu-studio, active-directory, kerberos, sssd

I am trying to join my freshly installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 to an AD domain hosted on my Synology NAS, by following the instructions in [this white paper](https://pages.ubuntu.com/rs/066-EOV-335/images/Integration_Ubuntu_Desktop_Final.pdf), starting on page 11 ("Joining After Installation via SSSD").

When I perform the recommended checks on pages 19-20 everything looks fine, but when I run:

```
systemctl status sssd
```

as suggested on page 21, I get the expected output as shown in the whitepaper, followed by 5 error messages like this:

```
tkey query failed: GSSAPI error: Major = Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, Minor = Server not found in Kerberos database.
```

The remaining tests on pages 21-24 using sssctl and samba-tool produce the expected results, but when I try to login (from an existing terminal session), I get:

```
login: Cannot possibly work without effective root
```

Since the login command is shown entered at what looks like a shell prompt rather than a terminal session prompt, I may have misunderstood the context.

IAC, what can/must I do about the Kerberos errors?
Presumably no AD login will be possible without a Kerberos server.

Comment: My concerns about not being able to login with an AD account were misplaced.  I was able to log in, but couldn't run Firefox in the account: probably a permissions problem.  I didn't set up set up pam_mkhomedir as recommended on page 17 of the instructions, because all users (both local and domain) already have home directories copied from a previous installation.  These appear to have the correct privileges, and the old home directory is working for the local admin account created during the installation.

Comment: P.S. "systemctl status sssd" now returns only two of the above cited tkey errors (from sssd); the remaining three have been replaced by:
"adcli[1434]: GSSAPI client step 1"
The tkey errors are now preceded by:
"sssd_nss[1110]: Enumeration requested but not enabled"
However, according to https://access.redhat.com/solutions/500433, this is not recommended anyway.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I can no longer log in to the GUI with a domain account.

Comment: "systemctl status sssd now also displays new error messages:
sssd_nss[1098]: Enumeration requested but not enabled
sssd[1273]: update failed: REFUSED
as well as the previously seen:
sssd[1287]: tkey query failed: GSSAPI error: Major = Unspecified GSS failure>
I am unaware of having done anything to change the configuration, other than installing updates listed in Discover after adding the recommended backports repositories.

Comment: I have undeleted my answer, even though I no longer consider it an answer, because it contains additional information which may be useful and was too long to include in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that DNSHostName in the domain contained only the server name of my Ubuntu Studio desktop and not the FQDN. As it proved difficult to change this, I used "realm leave" to remove the client machine from the domain, removed the Computer entry from the Doman Controller (DC) and rejoined the domain.  The only thing I am aware of doing differently is that I have left "use_fully_qualified_names = True" in "/etc/sssd/sssd.conf" instead of changing it to "False", an option mentioned at the bottom of page 16 in [the whitepaper](https://pages.ubuntu.com/rs/066-EOV-335/images/Integration_Ubuntu_Desktop_Final.pdf) Now things appear to work as expected.  The only peculiarities I have observed are as follows:

1. Due to setting the FQDN in "/etc/hostname" as described on page 10 of the whitepaper, both "hostname" *and* "hostname -f" return the FQDN.
2. "dig", "host". "nslookup" and "resolvectl query" all return an address of "127.0.1.1" (from 127.0.0.53#53) regardless of whether they are queried with the simple server name or the FQDN.
3. However, reverse lookup works as expected with "dig", "host", "nslookup" and "resolvectl query".  All of these return ,  and .local

None of this seems to cause any problems (so far ;-)

Comment: As mentioned above, I rejoiced too soon. It looks as though installing adsys as described on pp. 30-31 of the whitepaper broke login for domain accounts. When I try to "su" to a domain admin account, I get
"Error from server: error while updating policy: can't get policies for <FQDN>: requested a type computer of <FQDN> which isn't current host <simple hostname>."  Where is the <simple hostname> coming from??
"hostname", "hostname -f" and "hostnamectl status" all deliver the FQDN!!

Comment: After reading a long string of comments on reddit and finding a similar problem report on github, I have concluded that adsys is not yet ready for prime time.  After uninstalling adsys, I can log into the GUI as a domain user.  AD policy management would be nice, but it isn't essential for me and therefore not worth investing any more time.